# How do I do implicit conversion without creating a new instance?

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion, implicit

I've got a class which looks like this

```
class MyClass
{
    string myData;

    //.....
    //other fields

    public static implicit operator string(MyClass c)
    {
        return c.myData;
    }


}
```

Now when I assign the value of the class to a string, I get `myData`'s value. But in microsoft's [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx), to do implicit convection from `MyClass` to `string`, I'd have to create a new instance of `MyClass` in a static method. I don't want to do this, instead I want to simply assign the string's value to `myData` field.

Is this possible to do in c#, and if it is, how do I do it?

Comment: This is impossible as written: how can it possibly know which `MyClass` instance's `myData` to update?

Comment: If you want to update existing `myClass` instance, then make `myData` public property and simply assign new string value to this property `myClass.MyData = "new value";`

Comment: @TimS. yeah. that's what struck me. I envisioned it like this: `MyClass a=....; .... ;a="test";`

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like there is no direct solution to what you need. I would suggest to try operator overloading and this would allow to perform some of the things I think you need with the understanding that = (equal) cannot be overloaded probably you would like to try +=   You can find additional help here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fbs5e2h.aspx

This is a sample version:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public struct MyClass
    {
        public string MyData {get;set;}


        // Constructor. 
        public MyClass(string obj1):this()
        {
            this.MyData = obj1;
        }


        public static MyClass operator +(MyClass c1, string var3)
        {
            return new MyClass(var3);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return (System.String.Format("{0} ", this.MyData));
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute("D36900FE-8902-4ED8-B961-DE5B3F3273AC")]
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           MyClass obj1 = new MyClass();
            obj1 += "Hello";               
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is disgusting... but I like it? Have an upvote.